# How stack cubes together to form a multiresolution 3D grid without z-ordering issues?

Tags: python, artifacts

I am using scientific quantum chemistry software where we represent electronic orbitals in an adaptive grid based on multiresolution analysis and multiwavelets. I would like to generate a rendered image of such a multiresolution grid. I have successfully loaded in all the individual cubes that build up grid, but I am running into the issue with weird shading effects due to the faces of adjacent cubes occupying the same space.

The 260 cubes are defined by their origins and their sizes (length of their sides):

origins:

```
-32.0 -32.0 -32.0
-32.0 -16.0 -32.0
-32.0 -16.0 -16.0
-32.0 -32.0 -16.0
-16.0 -32.0 -16.0
-8.0 -16.0 -8.0
-16.0 -16.0 -8.0
-16.0 -8.0 -8.0
-8.0 -4.0 -4.0
-4.0 -2.0 -2.0
-4.0 -2.0 -4.0
-2.0 -2.0 -4.0
-2.0 -2.0 -2.0
-2.0 -4.0 -2.0
-2.0 -4.0 -4.0
-4.0 -4.0 -4.0
-4.0 -4.0 -2.0
-4.0 -8.0 -4.0
-8.0 -8.0 -4.0
-8.0 -8.0 -8.0
-4.0 -8.0 -8.0
-4.0 -4.0 -8.0
-8.0 -4.0 -8.0
-8.0 -8.0 -16.0
-16.0 -8.0 -16.0
-16.0 -16.0 -16.0
-8.0 -16.0 -16.0
-16.0 -16.0 -32.0
-16.0 -32.0 -32.0
0.0 -32.0 -32.0
0.0 -16.0 -32.0
0.0 -16.0 -16.0
8.0 -16.0 -16.0
8.0 -8.0 -16.0
0.0 -8.0 -16.0
4.0 -4.0 -8.0
4.0 -8.0 -8.0
0.0 -8.0 -8.0
0.0 -4.0 -8.0
0.0 -4.0 -4.0
2.0 -4.0 -4.0
2.0 -2.0 -4.0
0.0 -2.0 -4.0
0.0 -2.0 -2.0
2.0 -2.0 -2.0
2.0 -4.0 -2.0
0.0 -4.0 -2.0
0.0 -8.0 -4.0
4.0 -8.0 -4.0
4.0 -4.0 -4.0
8.0 -8.0 -8.0
8.0 -16.0 -8.0
0.0 -16.0 -8.0
0.0 -32.0 -16.0
16.0 -32.0 -16.0
16.0 -16.0 -16.0
16.0 -16.0 -32.0
16.0 -32.0 -32.0
-32.0 0.0 -32.0
-32.0 16.0 -32.0
-32.0 16.0 -16.0
-32.0 0.0 -16.0
-16.0 8.0 -8.0
-16.0 0.0 -8.0
-16.0 0.0 -16.0
-16.0 8.0 -16.0
-8.0 8.0 -16.0
-8.0 0.0 -16.0
-4.0 4.0 -8.0
-4.0 0.0 -8.0
-8.0 0.0 -8.0
-8.0 4.0 -8.0
-8.0 4.0 -4.0
-8.0 0.0 -4.0
-2.0 0.0 -2.0
-2.0 0.0 -4.0
-4.0 0.0 -4.0
-4.0 0.0 -2.0
-4.0 2.0 -2.0
-4.0 2.0 -4.0
-2.0 2.0 -4.0
-2.0 2.0 -2.0
-4.0 4.0 -4.0
-8.0 8.0 -8.0
-16.0 16.0 -16.0
-16.0 16.0 -32.0
-16.0 0.0 -32.0
0.0 0.0 -32.0
0.0 16.0 -32.0
0.0 16.0 -16.0
0.0 8.0 -8.0
0.0 4.0 -4.0
4.0 4.0 -4.0
4.0 0.0 -4.0
2.0 0.0 -2.0
0.0 0.0 -2.0
0.0 2.0 -2.0
2.0 2.0 -2.0
2.0 2.0 -4.0
0.0 2.0 -4.0
0.0 0.0 -4.0
2.0 0.0 -4.0
0.0 0.0 -8.0
4.0 0.0 -8.0
4.0 4.0 -8.0
0.0 4.0 -8.0
0.0 0.0 -16.0
0.0 8.0 -16.0
8.0 8.0 -16.0
8.0 0.0 -16.0
8.0 0.0 -8.0
8.0 8.0 -8.0
16.0 0.0 -16.0
16.0 16.0 -16.0
16.0 16.0 -32.0
16.0 0.0 -32.0
-32.0 -32.0 0.0
-32.0 -16.0 0.0
-32.0 -16.0 16.0
-32.0 -32.0 16.0
-16.0 -32.0 16.0
-16.0 -16.0 16.0
-8.0 -16.0 8.0
-16.0 -16.0 8.0
-16.0 -8.0 8.0
-8.0 -8.0 8.0
-8.0 -4.0 4.0
-4.0 -4.0 4.0
-4.0 -8.0 4.0
-8.0 -8.0 4.0
-8.0 -8.0 0.0
-4.0 -8.0 0.0
-4.0 -4.0 0.0
-4.0 -4.0 2.0
-2.0 -4.0 2.0
-2.0 -4.0 0.0
-1.0 -2.0 1.0
-1.0 -2.0 0.0
-2.0 -2.0 0.0
-2.0 -2.0 1.0
-2.0 -1.0 1.0
-2.0 -1.0 0.0
-1.0 -1.0 0.0
-1.0 -1.0 1.0
-2.0 -2.0 2.0
-4.0 -2.0 2.0
-4.0 -2.0 0.0
-8.0 -4.0 0.0
-16.0 -8.0 0.0
-16.0 -16.0 0.0
-8.0 -16.0 0.0
-16.0 -32.0 0.0
0.0 -32.0 0.0
0.0 -16.0 0.0
8.0 -16.0 0.0
8.0 -8.0 0.0
4.0 -4.0 0.0
4.0 -8.0 0.0
0.0 -8.0 0.0
0.0 -4.0 0.0
2.0 -4.0 0.0
2.0 -2.0 0.0
1.0 -1.0 0.0
1.0 -2.0 0.0
0.0 -2.0 0.0
0.0 -1.0 0.0
0.0 -1.0 1.0
0.0 -2.0 1.0
1.0 -2.0 1.0
1.0 -1.0 1.0
0.0 -2.0 2.0
2.0 -2.0 2.0
2.0 -4.0 2.0
0.0 -4.0 2.0
0.0 -4.0 4.0
0.0 -8.0 4.0
4.0 -8.0 4.0
4.0 -4.0 4.0
0.0 -8.0 8.0
8.0 -8.0 8.0
8.0 -16.0 8.0
0.0 -16.0 8.0
0.0 -16.0 16.0
0.0 -32.0 16.0
16.0 -32.0 16.0
16.0 -16.0 16.0
16.0 -16.0 0.0
16.0 -32.0 0.0
-32.0 0.0 0.0
-32.0 16.0 0.0
-32.0 16.0 16.0
-32.0 0.0 16.0
-16.0 0.0 16.0
-16.0 16.0 16.0
-16.0 16.0 0.0
-8.0 8.0 0.0
-8.0 8.0 8.0
-16.0 8.0 8.0
-16.0 8.0 0.0
-16.0 0.0 0.0
-16.0 0.0 8.0
-8.0 0.0 8.0
-4.0 0.0 4.0
-8.0 0.0 4.0
-8.0 4.0 4.0
-4.0 4.0 4.0
-4.0 4.0 0.0
-8.0 4.0 0.0
-8.0 0.0 0.0
-4.0 0.0 0.0
-4.0 2.0 0.0
-4.0 2.0 2.0
-4.0 0.0 2.0
-2.0 0.0 2.0
-2.0 2.0 2.0
-2.0 2.0 0.0
-1.0 1.0 0.0
-1.0 1.0 1.0
-2.0 1.0 1.0
-2.0 1.0 0.0
-2.0 0.0 0.0
-2.0 0.0 1.0
-1.0 0.0 1.0
-1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 2.0 0.0
0.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 2.0
2.0 0.0 2.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
2.0 2.0 0.0
2.0 0.0 0.0
4.0 0.0 0.0
4.0 4.0 0.0
0.0 4.0 0.0
0.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 0.0 4.0
0.0 0.0 4.0
0.0 0.0 8.0
8.0 0.0 8.0
8.0 0.0 0.0
8.0 8.0 0.0
8.0 8.0 8.0
0.0 8.0 8.0
0.0 8.0 0.0
0.0 16.0 0.0
0.0 16.0 16.0
0.0 0.0 16.0
16.0 0.0 16.0
16.0 16.0 16.0
16.0 16.0 0.0
16.0 0.0 0.0
```

Lengths:

```
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
8.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
16.0
```

I am adding the cubes to Blender via the following code:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np


f_origins = 'origins.txt'
f_lengths = 'lengths.txt'

origins = np.loadtxt(f_origins)
lengths = np.loadtxt(f_lengths)

def clear():
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    for ob in objects:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(ob, do_unlink=True)
        
    collections = bpy.data.collections
    for c in collections:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(c, do_unlink=True)
        
    materials = bpy.data.materials
    for mat in materials:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(mat, do_unlink=True)
        
def setup():
    # Add collections to hold objects
    scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
    coll_cubes = bpy.data.collections.new('Cubes')
    scene.collection.children.link(coll_cubes)
        
def addCube(origin=(0, 0, 0), length=1, id='Cube', explode_factor=0):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(id)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(id, mesh)
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    cube = bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=length)
    
    obj.location.x = origin[0] - origin[0] / 2 + origin[0] * explode_factor
    obj.location.y = origin[1] - origin[1] / 2 + origin[1] * explode_factor
    obj.location.z = origin[2] - origin[2] / 2 + origin[2] * explode_factor
    
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.free()
    
    bpy.data.collections["Cubes"].objects.link(bpy.data.objects[id])
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    clear()
    setup()
    for i, (o, l) in enumerate(zip(origins, lengths)):
        addCube(origin=o, length=l, id=f'GridCube_{i}')
```

Is there a clever way to get a clean representation of my custom cube grid?

The image below is a `matplotlib` generated figure, kind of similar to what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For a graphic result of this kind, to avoid fuss eliminating coincident faces, you might consider shading, not the object, but instead the World, as seen through it. In Cycles, set with a high 'Max Bounces' for transparency..

- Shade the object 100% transparent.
- Select 'World' at the left of the Shader Node Editor's header:

[image]

- Shade the World (using a *Light Path* node,) a colour dependent on the number of transparent surfaces the ray has passed on the way to the camera:

[image]

BTW, I could get Freestyle to stroke this correctly only by:

- Marking all edges Freestyle
- Setting up 2 identical Line Sets, one for Visible and one for Invisible lines. Unchecking the 'Visible' check-box didn't work.
- Switching off 'Chaining'.

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks! Could you share the blend file? I am a bit of a noob, so having the file would help a lot :) I am using Version 2.93.4

Comment: @Yoda [Here you go..](https://pasteall.org/media/4/5/45cc92e979d069633d3f5aa7496d612d.blend)  https://pasteall.org/blend/1cd3a6f6eb6e42209ba503d022480e30